# <img> tag wrong in IE8 only?

Tags: image, ie8-browser-mode

Why won´t my img tag work in IE8? but IN ff? and chrome?

```
validation Output: 2 Errors

 Line 17, Column 47: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter
"<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt"logga">"
✉
Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value".

 Line 17, Column 48: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
"<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt"logga">"
✉
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">".

 Line 17, Column 2: start tag was here
"<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt"logga">"
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the equals and closing the tag

```
<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt="logga" />

<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt="logga" />

<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt="logga" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an equal sign after `alt` and for XHTML you should close the img tag approprietly:

```
<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt="logga" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you've set your `DOCTYPE` to strict XHTML, which means your `img` tag isn't correctly formed, try either changing the `DOCTYPE` to a more loose version, or amend your img tags..

```
<img src="images/helhjartat_slutliga.jpg" alt="logga" />
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to write **alt="logga"** and not **alt"logga"**

and secondly you have to close your tag.

either you close you tag directly by replacing the trailing **>** with **/>** (optionally add a further space)

or you provide the closing tag

why is it working in FF and Chrome?
Because they are much more generous than - in this case - IE8

I hope this answers your question ;) 
If i got your question wrong, please forgive me